# Get value from select type by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a classic question but can't find the best approach. I have a dropdown with select type and 3 values (breakfast, candy , coffeeshop).

If value selected = breakfast then show div with class sf-field-post-meta-breakfast and only this one. div sf-field-post-meta-candy and sf-field-post-meta-coffeeshop must be hidden. I also want to make this happen when view is loaded so not only on change.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal .sf-input-select').change(function () {
    alert($(this).val);
    if($(this).val()=="breakfast")
       {
        $('.sf-field-post-meta-breakfast').show();
       }
       else
       {
        $('.sf-field-post-meta-breakfast').hide();
       }
    });
})
</script>
```

The problem is when change `sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal` the value send me like

```
function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=n.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,n(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":n.isArray(e)&&(e=n.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=n.valHooks[this.type]||n.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=n.valHooks[e.type]||n.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!==(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c?c.replace(rb,""):null==c?"":c)}}
```

Comment: `alert($(this).val);` needs to have `()` after val..

Comment: $('.sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal') 

or

    $('.sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal .sf-input-select')

which is the right selector for your select box? Share your HTML snippet as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html is like this (and note, I've added a class 'test-class' to make selection easier):

```
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal">
    <select class="sf-input-select">
        <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
        <option value="candy">Candy </option>
        <option value="coffeeshop">Coffeeshop</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="sf-field-post-meta-breakfast test-class" hidden>Breakfast description</div>
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-candy test-class" hidden>Candy description</div>
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-coffeeshop test-class" hidden>Coffeeshop description</div>
```

Adjust your script to this and it should work:-

```
$(function () {

    $('.sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal .sf-input-select').change(function () {
        // Hide all the divs using the 'test-class' selector
        $.each($('.test-class'), function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        // Check the value selected and show the associated div
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'breakfast':
                $('.sf-field-post-meta-breakfast').show();
                break;
            case 'candy':
                $('.sf-field-post-meta-candy').show();
                break;
            case 'coffeeshop':
                $('.sf-field-post-meta-coffeeshop').show();
                break;
        }
    });
    // Trigger 'change' when the html document has loaded to set the div visibility
    $('.sf-field-post-meta-typeofmeal .sf-input-select').trigger('change');

});
```

The reason you got the value you've given is because `alert($(this).val);` should be `alert($(this).val());`

Hope it helps.